# Updating of the asp.net dropdown control using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my ASP.Net default.aspx,  I have dropdown list control and following javascript code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGenres" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" DataTextField="cityID" DataValueField="cityID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGenres_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" >



<script type="text/javascript">
        var ddlClientID = '<%=ddlGenres.ClientID%>';
        //document.getElementById(ddlGenres)
        function SetddlVal(nIndx)
        {
            //$("#ddlGenres")
            var ddlListSelect = document.getElementById(ddlClientID);
            ddlList.SelectedIndex = nIndx;
        }
    </script>
```

====================================================================

In a external javascript file, I am calling the function SetddlVal.
I debugged the code and the ddlList selectedIndex is successfully changed within the script.

=====================================================================

The issue I am facing is, when the SelectedIndex value is changed in the javascript, The ddlGenres_SelectedIndexChanged code is not being triggered.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Thanks
Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript the property of an `<select>` input is `selectedIndex` not `SelectedIndex`.

Change your function to this:

```
function SetddlVal(nIndx)
{
    var ddlListSelect = document.getElementById('<%=ddlGenres.ClientID%>');
    ddlListSelect.selectedIndex = nIndx;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, appreciate you taking the time to answer the questions. I made the following changes to the function, but it still did not trigger the event handler "ddlGenres_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: updated code which did not help                                function SetddlVal(nIndx)
        {
            var ddlListSelect = document.getElementById('<%=ddlGenres.ClientID%>');
            ddlListSelect.index = nIndx;
            ddlList.index = nIndx;  //I think it should be ddlListSelect, but I have tried ddlList and ddlListSelect. 
        }

Comment: Is it actually changing the selection on your page?

Comment: No, it did not change the selection.

Comment: I realized there was a typo. Change `ddlList` to `ddlListSelect` or copy the code from my updated answer. Did that work? If not, what happens if you add `alert(ddlListSelect);` to your function?

Comment: Thank you Dave, That changed the value of the dropdown. It is still not triggering the event code for ddlGenres_SelectedIndexChanged. The alert shows "[object HTMLSelectElement]"